# Lambda Throttled Events Information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, throttling

I have a Lambda function with a Kinesis data stream attached as a trigger. Lambda is showing a high throttle count maybe because there are several invocations from Kinesis trigger and as the concurrency is 1000, it passes that number. My question is actually what happens to the throttled invocations. So Lambda tries to invoke it for 6 hours and even then if it fails, what happens to it? Can I get the payload information of the throttled events and the ones that get discarded after 6 hours of retry?

How can I know the sequence number or the Kinesis timestamp at which the throttling started to happen and then start the Lambda from that timestamp again maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure error-handling like in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html to define a dead letter queue, because to day, if your documents have a 6 hours for maximum age, they will simply be lost.